# How to custom Android Ratingbar Shape with numbering 1-10?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

It there any ways to customize the [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) to look like the image below? Default RatingBar is just stars. For now i managed to change the star and color to rectangle but failed to put number inside the RatingBar.

[image: Number inside RatingBar]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to customize your [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html). In `XML`

```
 <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/rating_bar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_star_rating" />
```

Use images of filled numbers and blank numbers in drawable as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/notfill_star" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/notfill_star" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/fill_star" />
```

You can try this [library](https://github.com/badoo/StarBar) too

Comment: OP is looking for something else!

Comment: @KishanSolanki he wanted to customize rating bar. And FYI solutions get changed after a while. You can post your answer instead of downvoting other's posts.